# Publish npm from jenkins

Tags: jenkins, npm, artifactory

I am new to jenkins. I want to know what is equivalent of
"`npm publish --registry...`" in Jenkins.

I have configured Artifactory plugin in Jenkins, but I don't know how to use that in my job.

When I do `npm publish` manually it automatically creates `.tgz` file with correct version number and add it to Artifactory.

How can I accomplish the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Jenkins Artifactory plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin) allows you to define the Artifactory server.

There is a deploy maven artifact section, but you could also simply consider a basic build step as an "Execute Windows batch command" or an "Execute shell" (for Linux), in which you can type the same command as the one you are typing manually.

You only need to make sure the environment variables used during that step by the account running Jenkins are the same as the account you are using when typing said command.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jfrog command line interface for this: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-BuildingNpmPackages

Just use `jfrog rt npm-publish` in place of `npm publish` and jfrog cli will take care of the rest.

Comment: `jfrog`, right! I must have missed it when I wrote my answer a year ago. +1

Comment: Yeah, I just wish there was a way to capture the information "jfrog rt npm-install" and "npm-publish" capture with the Jenkins plugin.  It's unfortunate that they (plugin and jfrog cli) cannot share information.  I setup the plugin with my pipeline and run multiple parallel steps, but with jfrog you can't capture and pass back to the plugin to roll it all up into a single build.

Comment: That sounds lame... Did you open a ticket to their support team?

Comment: No I haven't.  We have Artifactory Pro and that doesn't give us any support, so I can't raise tickets.  If you are able to, I'd love it if you raised it up with them.